# pandas groupby aggregate to dask

Tags: python, dask

I have a pandas code that would like to translate into Dask

Let's have a dummy data

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
df = pd.DataFrame({'item_id': [10, 10, 10, 8, 8, 8], 'rating': [3, 4, 2, 1, 2, 3]})
ddf = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=2)
```

here is the pandas code

```
bb = df[['item_id', 'rating']].\
        groupby(['item_id']).agg(
        item_hist_rating_up=pd.NamedAgg(column='rating', aggfunc=lambda x: round(100 * sum(x>=3.75) / len(x))),
        item_hist_rating_down=pd.NamedAgg(column='rating', aggfunc=lambda x: round(100 * sum(x<3.75) / len(x))),
        item_hist_rating_q25=pd.NamedAgg(column='rating', aggfunc=lambda x: np.quantile(x, q = 0.25 )),
        item_hist_rating_q75=pd.NamedAgg(column='rating', aggfunc=lambda x: np.quantile(x, q = 0.75 )),
        item_hist_rating_min=pd.NamedAgg(column='rating', aggfunc='min'),
        item_hist_rating_count=pd.NamedAgg(column='rating', aggfunc='count'),
        item_hist_rating_max=pd.NamedAgg(column='rating', aggfunc='max'),
        item_hist_rating_avg=pd.NamedAgg(column='rating', aggfunc=np.mean),
    ).reset_index().round(2)
bb
```

I know with Dask one can calculate four of these numbers as following

```
ddf.groupby(['item_id'])['rating'].aggregate(['sum', 'mean', 'max', 'min']).compute()
```

and two others like

```
ddf['rating'].ge(3.75).groupby(ddf['item_id']).mean().compute()
ddf['rating'].lt(3.75).groupby(ddf['item_id']).mean().compute()
```

but I couldn't figure out 1) how to do groupby.quantile - neither 2) how to concat these results ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import dask.dataframe as dd

stats_df = ddf.groupby(['item_id'])['rating'].aggregate(['sum', 'mean', 'max', 'min', 'count'])
stats_df['rating_up'] = ddf['rating'].ge(3.75).groupby(ddf['item_id']).mean() * 100
stats_df['rating_down'] = ddf['rating'].lt(3.75).groupby(ddf['item_id']).mean() * 100

q25 = ddf.groupby('item_id')['rating'].apply(
    lambda x: x.quantile(0.25))

q75 = ddf.groupby('item_id')['rating'].apply(
    lambda x: x.quantile(0.75))
  
qdf = dd.merge(stats_df, q25, left_index=True, right_index=True)
edf = dd.merge(stats_df, q75, left_index=True, right_index=True)
ldf = dd.merge(qdf, edf[['rating']], left_index=True, right_index=True)
ldf.columns = ['sum', 'mean', 'max', 'min', 'count', 'rating_up', 'rating_down', 'q25', 'q75']
ldf.compute().reset_index().round(2)
```

Output:

```
Out[24]: 
   item_id  sum  mean  max  min  count  rating_up  rating_down  q25  q75
0        8    6   2.0    3    1      3       0.00       100.00  1.5  2.5
1       10    9   3.0    4    2      3      33.33        66.67  2.5  3.5
```

Alternatively, use dask.delayed for parallel computation of pandas commands. According to their [documentation](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/delayed-best-practices.html), parallelism is achieved by having many delayed calls. Therefore, you aggregation is broken down into several delayed functions below.

```
from dask import delayed

@delayed
def rating_up(x):
    return x.groupby(['item_id']).agg(
        rating_up=pd.NamedAgg(column='rating', aggfunc=lambda x: round(100 * sum(x>=3.75) / len(x), 2)))

@delayed
def rating_down(x):
    return x.groupby(['item_id']).agg(
        rating_down=pd.NamedAgg(column='rating', aggfunc=lambda x: round(100 * sum(x<3.75) / len(x), 2)))

@delayed
def q_25(x):
    return x.groupby(['item_id']).agg(
        rating_q25=pd.NamedAgg(column='rating', aggfunc=lambda x: np.quantile(x, q=0.25 )))

@delayed
def q_75(x):
    return x.groupby(['item_id']).agg(
        rating_q75=pd.NamedAgg(column='rating', aggfunc=lambda x: np.quantile(x, q=0.75 )))

@delayed
def rating_min(x):
    return x.groupby(['item_id']).agg(
        rating_min=pd.NamedAgg(column='rating', aggfunc='min'))

@delayed
def rating_max(x):
    return x.groupby(['item_id']).agg(
        rating_max=pd.NamedAgg(column='rating', aggfunc='max'))

@delayed
def rating_count(x):
    return x.groupby(['item_id']).agg(
        rating_count=pd.NamedAgg(column='rating', aggfunc='count'))

@delayed
def rating_avg(x):
    return x.groupby(['item_id']).agg(
        rating_avg=pd.NamedAgg(column='rating', aggfunc=np.mean))


def stats(x):
    count_ = rating_count(x)
    up = rating_up(x)
    down = rating_down(x)
    q25 = q_25(x)
    q75 = q_75(x)
    rate_min = rating_min(x)
    rate_max = rating_max(x)
    rate_avg = rating_avg(x)
    ddf = count_.join(up).join(down).join(q25).join(q75).join(rate_min).\
        join(rate_max).join(rate_avg)
    return ddf

stats_df = stats(df)
print(stats_df.compute().reset_index().round(2))
```

Output:

```
   item_id  rating_count  rating_up  rating_down  rating_q25  rating_q75  rating_min  rating_max  rating_avg
0        8             3       0.00       100.00         1.5         2.5           1           3           2
1       10             3      33.33        66.67         2.5         3.5           2           4           3
```

Comment: Thanks - is it possible to leverage aggregate function ? and avoid merge ? (I am just thinking performance wise - my data is huge) ? don't you think that would be smarter ?

Comment: According to Dask's documentation merging on indices is fast. https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe-best-practices.html

Comment: I was trying to do sth like -> ddf.groupby('item_id').agg({'rating': ['min', 'max', 'count', 'mean', custom1, custom2, custom3]}) - is that sth you can add to you answer ? I am sure future visitors will appreciate it a lot as there are not many similar examples.

Comment: Not without spending hours/days trying to do accomplish this. Dask's quantile method behaves rather oddly.

Comment: Thanks - I understand - 1) do you have opinion on the performance of delayed vs earlie solution ? 2) do you think I can use a numpy for quantile and use it through dask ? I appreciate your help

Comment: In situations like yours I would test whether there is a difference in performance between dask.delayed and dask data frame. Performance will undoubtedly depend on your data set and on the transformations in your flow. I have had good results with dask dataframe, but would still experiment with both if had all the data. On 2) ddf.groupby('item_id')['rating'].apply(lambda x: np.quantile(x, 0.25)) also works and np.quantile is also used in the dask.delayed solution. By the way, at least in pandas custom aggregations come with a performance price. I presume this holds for Dask as well.

Comment: I don't understand why someone should down vote your answer ! I just upvote and accepted.

Comment: I don't understand either. I think the dask data frame part looks a bit weird because of the the several merges. However, the present solution is the only way I could make dask data frame work with the quantile calculation. Everything else resulted in errors and it took me a good two hours to get passed them. I am going to raise this as an issue with the Dask contributors. By the way, if your summary stats data is not too large, you could invoke the compute method after each stats calculation with Dask, and then merge using pandas. +1 from me as well for a well constructed question.